# Secondary button icon not showing in JQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui

I am learning a JQuery tutorial where I am intended to display a JQuery button with primary and secondary icons. The instructor's button looks like this:

[image]

The same code for me displays a button like this:

[image]

My code:

```
<!Doctype HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="button1">Button 1</button>

        <script>
            $('#button1').button({
                icons: {
                    primary: 'ui-icon-mail-closed',
                    secondary: 'ui-icon-caret-1-e'
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when I comment out the `primary: '...'` option, I can see the secondary button, but not both. Has JQueryUI changed? How can I show 2 icons on the button like the instructor's?

Comment: I do not see `icons` as a option for Buttons: https://api.jqueryui.com/button/

Comment: IDK but the instructor is teaching that. The video is from 2015... Maybe it's deprecated?

Comment: Yes, I found in the older docs a reference to it: https://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/button/ so maybe use the jQuery 1.11.4 library instead? Or add the Control Group maybe.

Comment: Ok, sure... Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: The button widget was rewritten in 1.12. Some options changed, you can find documentation for the old options in the 1.11 button docs. This widget used to bundle support for inputs of type radio and checkbox, this is now deprecated, use the checkboxradio widget instead. It also used to bundle the buttonset widget, this is also deprecated, use the controlgroup widget instead.

So the Quick Fix is to use older Library: 1.11.4. Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button1').button({
    icons: {
      primary: 'ui-icon-mail-closed',
      secondary: 'ui-icon-caret-1-e'
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Button 1</button>
```

This works.

The other method would be to add the element manually or use Controlgroup.